Condition on coefficients of a power-series for getting a specific limit value
I have a very specific convergent power-series of the form,
$$
I(k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \left(kx_0\right)^{2n}
$$
In my physical problem, I have the condition that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} I(k) \sim k^{-2}
$$
In order to achieve this limit, what should be the condition on the coefficients $c_n$?
I should also note that I have an additional strict condition that $c_0 \ne 0$. This is imposed so that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow 0} I(k) = c_0
$$
I am citing two typical examples which can satisfy these limits,

Consider
$$
c_n = \frac{(-1)^n (kx_0)^{2n}}{(n+1)!}
$$
in which case, we have
$$
I(k) = k^{-2} \left[ 1 - e^{-(kx_0)^2} \right]
$$

In the second case, we can take
$$
c_n = \frac{(-1)^n (kx_0)^{2n}}{(2n+3)!}
$$
for which we will have,
$$
I(k) = (kx_0)^{-2} \left[1 - \frac{\sin (kx_0)}{kx_0} \right]
$$


Physical intuition
The physical intuition of this problem emerges from the requirement for a diffusion problem wherein the solution takes the following form in the Fourier-space
$$
\tilde P(k,t) = \exp \bigg[ - k^2 I(k) \frac{t}{\tau} \bigg]
$$
where $\tilde P(k,t)$ is the Fourier transform of the probability density $P(x,t)$.

The condition that $c_0 \ne 0$, ensures that the system achieves the Gaussian behaviour in the limit $kx_0 \rightarrow 0$.
The condition that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} I(k) \sim k^{-2}
$$
is required to ensure that in the limit $kx_0 \rightarrow \infty$ (i.e. to say physically in short distances limit), $\tilde P(k,t)$ is independent of $k$. Therefore, the corresponding Fourier transform in this limit will simply be $P(x,t) \sim \delta(x) e^{-t/\tau}$, since we are looking at small distances.


The problem is that the power series doesn't converge in the example you provided as the limit eventually strays outside of the region of convergence of the power series $|kx_0|<1$. I would be doubtful that you can make any precise statements about the asymptotic behavior of the anti limit portion of the function from the local series centered at $kx_0=0$ alone.

Could you perhaps give more insight into the physical problem to deal with the convergence more intuitively? Thanks

@NinadMunshi Thank you for pointing this out! I have modified the question to provide new examples. Hopefully these are more consistent.

@by24 I have also added some physical intuition to provide more context to the problem. Hope it helps
